# How to take Bitmap from Canvas from particular position in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I captured bitmap from canvas but it's taking my whole Drawview.But I want to take Bitmap from particular position of canvas.Means I draw a paint on canvas that time I have MinX,MaxX and MinY,MaxY positions based on this positions I want to take bitmap with in this positions.Is it possible?.

My code for taking Bitmap from canvas :

```
public void save(View v)
    {
        Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
        Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
        if(mBitmap == null)
        {
            mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);;
        }
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

            v.draw(canvas);
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
            mFileOutStream.flush();
            mFileOutStream.close();
            String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
            Log.v("log_tag","url: " + url);
            //In case you want to delete the file
            //boolean deleted = mypath.delete();
            //Log.v("log_tag","deleted: " + mypath.toString() + deleted);
            //If you want to convert the image to string use base64 converter

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your code goes like this:

```
Bitmap mDrawBitmap;
Canvas mBitmapCanvas;
Paint drawPaint = new Paint();

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (mDrawBitmap == null) {
        mDrawBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBitmapCanvas = new Canvas(mDrawBitmap);
    }

    // draw on the btimapCanvas
    //... and more
    mBitmapCanvas.drawWhatever(...);

    // after drawing with the bitmapcanvas,
    //all drawn information is stored in the Bitmap       

    // draw everything to the screen
    canvas.drawBitmap(mDrawBitmap, 0, 0, drawPaint);
}
```

Then, you can **crop the original** `Bitmap` using this code snippet:

```
public void save() {

    // crop the bitmap to your desired dimensions
    Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDrawBitmap, startX, startY, width, height);

    //... do the saving
}
```

Comment: Means, In your code At starting in onDraw() are you creating Transparent bitmap and what ever action I am doing on canvas those actions are done on mDrawBitmap right?.And at the time of saving bitmap I have crop the mDrawBitmap right?.

Comment: Whenever drawing on mDrawCanvas, the drawn actions will be on mDrawBitmap, since mDrawCanvas has been initialized with mDrawBitmap. Yes, opon saving, you crop mDrawBitmap as shown in the code above.

Comment: Hi @Philipp When I am creating bitmap in onDraw() I am getting OutOfMemory exception.How I can sample this bitmap?I stuck in this functionality from last 2 weeks

Comment: How large is your bitmap? In pixels? You could try using Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 instead or ARGB_8888. This will half your memory consumption.

Comment: Hi @Philipp I tried your solution.But,it's not working properly.When I am cropping bitmap always taking 0,0 x and y coordinates.As you can said I provide startX and start y also.Please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400602/how-to-draw-bitmap-from-argb-8888-bitmap